# Error 404 Spring-MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying spring-mvc and json.

My project arch is

```
src
--main
----java
----resource
----webapp
------WEB-INF
--------web.xml
--------jodoCmsDispatcher-servlet.xml
```

I have one plain controller

```
public class CategoryController {   
    @RequestMapping(value = "/kfc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Shop addCategory(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("parentid") String parentCategoryId, @PathVariable("newcategorytitle") String newcategorytitle )
    {
        Shop shop = new Shop();
        shop.setName("Testing");
        shop.setStaffName(new String[]{"11", "22"});
        return shop;
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB_INF/jodoCmsDispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jodoCmsDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jodoCmsDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

jodoCmsDispatcher-servlet.xml

```
.
.
<context:component-scan base-package="com.jodo.cms.controllers" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

I have tried following url (each time got 404)

```
localhost - - [05/Apr/2014:11:43:41 +0530] "GET /jodocms/kfc/ HTTP/1.1" 404 949
localhost - - [05/Apr/2014:11:44:20 +0530] "GET /jodocms/kfc HTTP/1.1" 404 949
localhost - - [05/Apr/2014:11:44:24 +0530] "GET /jodocms/ HTTP/1.1" 404 949
```

Project is deployed successfully in tomcat as shown in localhost:8080/manager

I am trying to sent json data and following "http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/"

What am i missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really needed

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB_INF/jodoCmsDispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

As DispatcherServlet by default load the jodoCmsDispatcher-servlet.xml, so remove those lines, that config is only used to add another applicationContext files

And CategoryController  must to be marked with `@Controller` to be scanned

Also consider change

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.jodo.cms.controllers" />
```

to

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.jodo.cms" />
```

Try removing..

```
@PathVariable("parentid") String parentCategoryId,
@PathVariable("newcategorytitle") String newcategorytitle
```

Those are causing the conflict as your URL is not correct, so left the method.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/kfc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Shop addCategory(HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        Shop shop = new Shop();
        shop.setName("Testing");
        shop.setStaffName(new String[]{"11", "22"});
        return shop;
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Koitoer, thx for quick reply. I have added "@Controller" annotation and changed as you suggested, but still outcome is same 'GET /jodocms/kfc HTTP/1.1" 404 949'

Comment: I make a update in my answer, the problem is PathVariable expect some url approach that you are not sending